# Import sql data from a large file when installing plugin

Tags: plugins, installation

I'm making my first plugin and I need to import about 31,000 records from a sql file into the wpdb when the plugin first gets installed by the user, but it is only importing about half of them only, around 18,000 records.

In the install function I have these lines to INSERT the data:

```
$sql = file_get_contents(ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/plugin-name/sql.sql');
dbDelta($sql);
```

Within the sql file I have this:

```
<? $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table_name (
`book` int(11) default NULL, 
`chapter` int(11) default NULL,
`verse` int(11) default NULL, 
`text` text
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO $table_name VALUES 
(4, 6, 27, 'text string here'),
(4, 6, 28, 'text string here'),
(4, 6, 29, 'text string here'),
(4, 6, 30, 'text string here');
"; ?>
```

I have tried using wpdb->query and wpdb->prepare but it is still not working. I have tried so many different ways and spent lots of hours trying to figure it out but it doesn't work.

What can I do so that I can import 100% of the records when the plugin gets installed?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'll guess that there's no way to reliably import 31,000 rows of data on all server setups in one go, you'll run into execution time errors, which is possibly what's happening to you. Check error logs. I'd suggest exploring ways to do this asynchronously in batches.

Comment: I got it! If anyone would later one need this, here it is.

`code`
...
 require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/plugin_name/sql.php');
 
 require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
 dbDelta($sql);
`code`

The sql.php looks like:

`code`
 $sql .= $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table_name (
  `col1` int(11) default NULL,
  `col2` text
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8"));

$sql2 .= $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO $table_name(`col1`, `col2`)
 VALUES 
(1, 1, 1, 'text string.'),
(1, 1, 2, 'text string.'),
(1, 1, 3, 'text string.')"));
`code`